# C# Azure IoT Hub how to get public IP address of devices

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-iot-hub

Given the device itself or its own twin, how can I obtain its public IP address?

I was reading the Microsoft APIs for Azure IoT Hub with no results.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you going to do with the public IP address of a **device** that already "calls home" by design?

Comment: It's a nice question without answer: customer hasn't specified this request.

Comment: @evilSnobu if you don't know where your devices are located the IP addresses might allow your to roughly figure out their location (like what country they are in right now,..)

Answer (score -1):

You can use “nslookup” to get the IP address of the IoT Hub.

Ex: nslookup IoTHubname.azure-devices.net

Note that, once you have created an IoT hub in an Azure region, the IoT hub keeps the same IP address for the lifetime of that IoT hub. However, if Microsoft moves the IoT hub to a different scale unit to maintain quality of service, then it is assigned a new IP address.

Also, check this feedback item on the [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/15714243-iot-hub-network-address) forum and upvote.

Comment: Dear, there's a misunderstanding: I needn't the IoT Hub's IP addresses but of all connected devices...

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394162/how-can-i-get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-device-on-azure-iot-hub

Comment: It offers same result you linked in your answer