# Azure IoTHub: Get IP Address / Location of connected devices

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I want to query the public IP address or geolocation of a device connected to Azure IoTHub.
I found a question on this topic from almost 3 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394162/how-can-i-get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-device-on-azure-iot-hub).
But the answer is not really what I am looking for. Does anyone know if there is a new function directly in IoTHub or Azure Functions for this task by now?

Comment: Can I ask what you don't like about the answer given on that other question? There is no built-in feature for this in IoT Hub.

Comment: Sure, because we are not using a device twin for this project so far. It seems a bit excessive to me to use a device twin only for the realisation of the geolocation function.
Maybe I'll push the ip via a telemetrie message to azure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there's no built-in functionality in Azure IoT Hub to achieve this. The answer previously given by [Rita Han](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6601582/rita-han) is still correct. I wanted to get into a little bit more detail though.

If you have access to GPS, you can store that in the reported properties of the device twin. If there is no GPS available, you can store the public IP of your device in the reported properties instead, and use an external API to resolve an approximate location.

As you mentioned in a comment, you could also send the IP in a telemetry message. This will work as well, but the benefit of the device twin is that it's available when the device is offline as well, without any storage resource (the device twin lives in the hub). Looking at the effort of both cases, they both take exactly one message to send the IP to IoT Hub. The difference is that if you're using MQTT, you [can listen for a confirmation message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#update-device-twins-reported-properties) in case you're updating reported properties.

Comment: Great, thank you for the detailed answer and the clarification of the benefits using a device twin. In my case uploaded data must be linked with the geolocation, the device can move between different locations in it's lifetime. So in my case it would be better to  send the file name of the log data and the corresponding geo-location via telemetry and save this information in a logfile...